# in Python, 'else' clause of if/else statement never fires

Tags: python

I am a beginner with Python. I can not get the last else statement to work in this code:

```
for row in result:
    how_many = len(row)
    for num in range(0, how_many):
        pprint(" row: " + str(num))
        c_as_str = str(row[num])
        print(c_as_str)    
        if num == 9: 
            if c_as_str != '':
                c = json.loads(c_as_str)  
                pprint(c)
        else: 
            print(" here is the row: ")
            pprint(c_as_str)
```

I am fetching rows out of the database. The 10th column (index 9) is some JSON stored as a string. So for that row, I need to convert it to JSON. For all the other strings, I just want to print them as strings.

The final else statement never fires. Why? There are 15 columns in each row. I would expect 14 of those columns would be printed in the else statement, but it never happens. Can

Comment: so what gets printed out?

Comment: Debug your stuff by printing out e. g. `how_many` or `num` in the inner loop.  The code as it stands here should do what you described, so I guess this is a bug in somthing you didn't show us.

Comment: provide the 'result' variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works:

`from pprint import pprint
for row in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]:
    how_many = len(row)
    for num in range(0, how_many):
        pprint(" row: " + str(num))
        c_as_str = str(row[num])
        print(c_as_str)
        if num == 9:
            if c_as_str != '':
                c = json.loads(c_as_str)
                pprint(c)
        else:
            print(" here is the row: ")
            pprint(c_as_str)`

Output:

```
' row: 0'
1
 here is the row: 
'1'
' row: 1'
2
 here is the row: 
'2'
' row: 2'
3
 here is the row: 
'3'
' row: 0'
4
 here is the row: 
'4'
' row: 1'
5
 here is the row: 
'5'
' row: 2'
6
 here is the row: 
'6'
```